# Sometimes EXC_BAD_ACCESS and sometimes unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have this issue and I looked over a lot of topics but didn't find an answer and I am using Swift.

I am sending an asynchronous request to a url and it returns to me a xml code which I parse and arrange its content in Custom objects in `NSMutableArray` as usual.

Let's say that array are containing 3 objects of the class `AppsObject` which contain ID, URLstring of an image, Text and URLstring to use it later for `UIButton` to go to specified url page by the browser.

I made a class named `AppsView` which has a naked initialiser and another initialiser which customize the view position and size and add an ImageIcon and a button for the link referred above.

in the main view controller I am initiating the appview in for loop to make several appviews that contain the NSmutableArray data.

I get the error message because of the UIButton that has been genereated dynamically and set the (addTarget) to a function in the same object.

Can someone help me?
You will find the code below:

```
class AppView: NSObject {

    var BackView = UIView()
    var AppIconView = UIImageView()
    var DescriptionLabel = UILabel()
    var LinkIcon = UIImageView()
    var AppNo:Int!
    var DescriptionText:String!

    let originView:UIView!
    let LinkImage = UIImage(named: "HyperLink.png")
    var LinkButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

    let BackViewHeight:CGFloat = 130.0
    let AppIconSize:CGFloat = 110.0
    let Inset:CGFloat = 5.0
    let BackgroundAlpha:CGFloat = 0.5
    let LinkButtonSize:CGFloat = 35.0
    let LinkButtonURL = NSURL()



    override init() {
        super.init  ()
    }

    init(sourceView:UIView, AppIconURLString: String , LoadedDescription: String , ObjectNo: Int , LinkButtonURL: NSURL){
        super.init()

        originView = sourceView
        ImagesLoader.downloadImage(NSURL(string: AppIconURLString)!, handler: {image, error in
            self.AppIconView.image = image
        })

        DescriptionText = LoadedDescription
        AppNo = ObjectNo

        setupAppView()
    }


    func setupAppView() {
        //SetupBackView
        BackView.frame = CGRectMake(Inset,
                                    Inset + (CGFloat(AppNo) * 140.0),
                                    originView.bounds.size.width - (Inset * 2),
                                    BackViewHeight)

        BackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(BackgroundAlpha)

        BackView.clipsToBounds = false
        originView.addSubview(BackView)

        //SetupAppIconView
        AppIconView.frame = CGRectMake(BackView.bounds.size.width - AppIconSize - Inset*2, Inset*2, AppIconSize, AppIconSize)

        AppIconView.clipsToBounds = false
        BackView.addSubview(AppIconView)

        //SetupLabelView
        DescriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(Inset, Inset, BackView.bounds.size.width - Inset - AppIconSize - Inset, AppIconSize)
        DescriptionLabel.text = DescriptionText
        DescriptionLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        BackView.addSubview(DescriptionLabel)

        //SetupButtonView
        LinkButton.frame = CGRectMake(Inset, BackView.bounds.size.height - LinkButtonSize - Inset, LinkButtonSize, LinkButtonSize)
        LinkButton.setImage(LinkImage, forState: .Normal)
        LinkButton.addTarget(self, action: "GotoLinkURL:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        LinkButton.tag = AppNo
        BackView.addSubview(LinkButton)
    }

    func GotoLinkURL(sender:UIButton!) {
        println(sender.tag)
    }

}
```

Comment: And where exactly do you encounter the error in the code?

Comment: When I click in the button (LinkButton) and it goes to appdelegate, sometimes it prints the sender tag and Sometimes EXC_BAD_ACCESS and sometimes unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I found out where was my problem. I read some of the Apple memory management and read about NSZombie which make me know that the NSObject is removed from the memory because of multiple reasons and that are: 1) I didn't declare it in the beginning of the calling class that is MainViewController so when it complete all the initiating procedures, it closes and removed from the memory and so GotoLinkURL function is not exist. 2) Then I declared in the MainViewController but I figured out that the last object only is exist in the memory so Hold all the object in an array and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where was my problem. I read some of the **Apple memory management** and read about *NSZombie* which make me know that the `NSObject` is removed from the memory because of multiple reasons and that are:

1) I didn't declare it in the beginning of the calling class that is `MainViewController` so when it complete all the initiating procedures, it closes and removed from the memory and so `GotoLinkURL` function does not exist.

2) Then I declared in the `MainViewController` but I figured out that the last object only is exist in the memory because I was calling it in for loop statements so I Held all the `NSObjects` in an array and that did the trick.